# Listener for total completed threads over time

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm new in JMeter, my question is if there is a listener that records "Total" threads over time available, or how can I create it. By saying "Thread" I mean the whole process inside the thread, PER USER. for example, if a thread contains 10 virtual users and approximately finish one loop in one minute, therefore I have 10 total in first minute, 20 in minute 2, and so on.

For example, I want to know how many times a thread was run at the end of test or at a certain time.

Answer (score 1):

I just defined a unique reference name for each individual counter and then added a Beanshell PostProcessor at the Thread's end. Counter start was set as 1 with Increment of 1 (Duh!)

In the Beanshell PostProcessor, set the Parameters box as ${your_counter_reference} and an easy script to see the number in the console: System.out.println("counter x:"+ ${your_counter_reference})

When you stop the test, look for biggest number of each thread in the console.